# Good software to perform simulations on polymer (absorption spectra)?

Tags: computational-chemistry, polymers

Sorry guys,I'm totally new in this field,for personal interest I'd like to start some calculations on conducting polymers ,could someone suggest a good software to perform simulations on polymer (absorption spectra)?

Comment: I echo @Martin-マーチン. While there are many groups that do similar work, my group certainly runs these types of calculations - but your question  is currently too broad to answer well.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_quantum_chemistry_and_solid-state_physics_software || For solid state check programs with PW-style basis sets. Beware, that calculating adsorption specra may be much harder than for common gaussian/gamess.

Answer (score 4):

**It depends very significantly on what you want to accomplish.**

I'm not going to suggest software, since there are many programs that can (and are) used to predict optical absorption spectra of conjugated polymers.

First, you can either approximate the properties of the polymer by running several calculations on oligomers (e.g., dimer, trimer, tetramer, etc.) and extrapolating the polymer band gap. Because conjugated polymers are similar to the particle-in-a-box model, you can [roughly](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.68.035204) plot the HOMO-LUMO gap or excitation energy vs. 1/(# of repeat units) and get an [approximately](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.68.035204) linear fit.

If you want more information, you could instead run a calculation on a polymer in a periodic unit cell, which will give you the electronic structure of the infinite system (but no information on disorder).

As suggested in the comment above, you can use multiple programs and different computational approaches depending on:

- What kind of polymer
- What kind of information you want
- What computational resources you have
- How accurately you want the information

The two most common methods for predicting optical absorption energies are the ZINDO/S semiempirical method, and TDDFT. The latter is [more accurate](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/jp025999m) particularly for predicting absorption intensity from the oscillator strength of the excitation energies.

Comment: Yeah,thank you!Geoff. I'm not totally new..well I've worked already in research several years,I've used always CASSCF,CASPT2,TDDFT,and interface for using Molecular Dynamics. I've always used Gaussian,Molcas,Turbomole always with University Licence. Never work with polymers before...and now I was just wondering if someone can suggest some free software suitable for polymers. Any suggestion is welcome! even a website to download some .xyz geometries, because as fr protein there are PDB files, I was wondering if there is some similar database for polymers.Thank you!

Comment: I'm biased, since I'm the creator, by I suggest http://avogadro.cc/

Comment: For example, if you want to set up a [unit cell for a polythiophene](http://manual.avogadro.cc/content/3-building-materials/3-building-a-polymer-unit-cell.html). But you can also build a monomer and copy/paste to grow the chain.